# Field Dependencies & Formulas

Tags: formula, validation-rule, field-dependencies

I have got two picklists with Field Dependencies:
"CODE" & "TEXT"
e.g. (Code = A99) --> (Text = "Diodes")

I like to have an automatism field filling, when a value in CODE is picked the field TEXT is filled automatically.

How do I do this?

Comment: you want to create two dependent picklist? if yes then this the link for https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm

Comment: Not exactly.
I have got two picklists that are dependent already, with a one to one dependence. One CODE Value got one TEXT Value not more.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a better way to do this would be to have a lookup to your Codes in a related object. This would work provided there is always a 1:1 relationship between the value in Codes and Text.

You could then drive the Text value using a cross-object formula field that also showed the text value.

So the steps:

1. Create a second object called "Code"
2. Keep the name field as Text type but label it "Code"
3. Add a custom field called "Text"
4. Create a lookup relationship field in the object where you are now fiddling around with picklists
5. Add another field, a formula field to the same object: return type is text and the formula points to Code__r.Text__c

There are some downsides:

- Lookups relationship fields can be a bit more fiddly for users
- You're burning a custom object (possibly an issue in EE orgs)

But there are an upside:

- It is a lot easier to load new code values into an object as data than it is to fiddle with keeping two independent picklists in sync.

Comment: Unfortunately the dataloader does not accept the entries to the Lookupfield "Code" Class id: id value of incorrect type: B99

Comment: Not to be obtuse, but I'm not sure what you mean...maybe you need a new question.